# Expose one or many objects via WCF

Tags: c#, performance, wcf

My database is structured using class table inheritance structure. As an example, one 'complete' business object is built from 8 tables with anywhere between 4 - 10 fields (excluding the ID field).

Would I be better off to expose one big object through WCF (with ~40 fields) or expose the smaller ones but have ~16 Operation Contracts?

As an aside, which of these would perform better?

Comment: how big is `one big object`? WCF is very good at it.

Comment: Difficult to say, it depends on the data. Are we talking primitives or are we talking large binary data, what is the frequency of the requests, is it a get only operation, are they crud operations? And so on. Also Do you need all the data in the first request or do you only need parts of the data?

A basic idea is, you only request the least amount of data needed for your applicaiton to work. Redundant data is wasted bandwith.

This question might need some more details to tell you the best approach.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, about 40 fields, mostly strings, numbers and dates,

Comment: @woutervs, Primitives mostly, a few dates, no binary data (yet). The requests could be anywhere between 10 - 100 an hour. Depending on what's being done. The most frequent requests are done with really small objects. (3 fields, string data). I probably won't need all the data at once, I could probably request more when my UI is a specific state.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I will be updating one table at a time, but I'm wondering if it's better from a performance POV to get all of the data first, and then updating the respective tables, rather than pulling and sending data when it's needed.

Comment: They are all fairly low weight requests so I'd go with multiple requests with only the data needed for an update. It will make your code more maintable. Performance wise it won't make a differnece if you are only going to be sending 10/100 requests an hour. And the smaller request will be faster on their own anyway since they need to carry less unneeded weight anyway.

Comment: @woutervs, So there won't be any problems having 16 or so operation contracts in a service? I only ask as I remember reading somewhere that the recommended maximum was 12-13.

Comment: You are correct, then again no one says you can only have one service ;)

Comment: I know, that, there's probably going to be 5-6 services, but some of them are still going to have 12+ contracts in them.

Comment: Like with anything else, the "best solution" is a compromise between the two extremes you just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the clients will use the data from the service side.
There are basically 4 steps related to the overall performance:

1. Generate the data objects
2. Serialize the data objects
3. Available bandwidth.
4. Hand-shaking of networking

Serialization generally has a linear performance over data size, so serialization upon one big object or many small objects will not result in significant performance differences.

Chatty conversation may require more had-shaking which could be time consuming. So if the logic of your client application could be well adapting using 1 big object from the service, so you may go just 1 client call to get all data needed, rather than many client calls with many hand-shakes. Thus perform better.